# Why is my test not loading my page object file? (Nightwatch.js)

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

This is the code I am using to run my tests

```
this is my config file. 
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "./pages/affirm.js",
  "globals_path" : "./data/data_for_requestinfo.js",

  "selenium" : {
   "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "/Users/davidcastro/Automation/bin/selenium-server-
standalone-3.4.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : 
    "/Users/davidcastro/Automation/Drivers/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : 
 "/Users/davidcastro/Automation/Drivers/geckodriver",
  "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "https://www.affirmpronebiopsy.com/",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "marionette": true
      }

    },
     "brevera" : {
      "launch_url" : "https://prod.breverabiopsy.com/",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
     "desiredCapabilities": {
       "browserName": "chrome"
      }
   },

    "edge" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
       }
      }
   }
}



This is my page file

module.exports = {
  elements: {
     name: {
      selector: "input[type=text]"
    },
   email: {
      selector: 'input[type=email]'
    },
    country:{
      selector: 'select[id=edit-country]'
    },
    submit: {
      selector: 'input[id=edit-submit]'
    }
  }
};
```

This is my test file

```
 module.exports = {
 'Request info ' : function (client) {
 var data = client.globals;
  var myPageObject = client.page.affirm(); 

client
   .url(client.launch_url + '/request-info')
   .waitForElementPresent('body', 1000)
   .setValue("@name", [data.name, client.Keys.ENTER])
   .pause(1000)
   .setValue('@email', [data.email])
   .pause(1000)
   .setValue('@country', [data.country])
   .pause(1000)
   .click('@submit')
   .pause(1000)
   .assert.containsText('main', 'Thank you for your interest!')
   .saveScreenshot('./screenshots/search-result.png')
   .pause(1000)
   .end();
```

}
 };

I tried changed the path several times in my config file to this: ./pages, 
and changed the way i called it in my test to this: var page= client.page() and that runs my test, but without the fields i named in my page file, so i get errors.

with the config mentioned above i get this error: [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuBuf.png)

is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Page object path should be a directory , not a file

```
"page_objects_path" : "./pages"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `nightwatch.conf.js` file is in the same directory as the `data` and `pages`, try writing the path without the initial '.' in front. For example:

```
"page_objects_path" : "/pages/affirm.js"
```

Comment: I have tried this and i still get the error mentioned above.